# ZSH Cull Old Aliases

Tags: shell, zsh, alias, oh-my-zsh

When I call `alias` in a zsh shell, I get a list of aliases. Some of them are desired, some are not. I originally created a `.alias` file in my home directory, and added `source $HOME/.alias` to my `.zshrc`. How do I cull any existing alias that is not part of the file being sourced by my `.zshrc`? (Presumably I could do this one by one with `unalias`, but that seems incredibly cumbersome.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unalias` supports unsetting multiple aliases at the same time, so you do not have to do this one by one, necessarily.

I would suggest just dropping all aliases and reload them anew from `~/.alias`.

```
unalias ${(k)aliases} ${(k)galiases} ${(k)saliases}; source
```

This requires the `zsh/parameter` module to be loaded. Check with `zmodload | grep parameter`, load with `zmodload zsh/parameter`.

The parameters `aliases`, `galiases` and `saliases` map the names of regular, global and suffix aliases respectively to their expansions. `${(k)parameter}` is substituted by the keys of `parameter`.

---

If you cannot load the module for some reason, you can work around it by using the output of the `alias` command:

```
unalias $(alias | cut -d = -f 1) ; source ~/.alias
```

If you only want to unset a specific kind of alias, use `alias -r` for regular aliases (those used instead of commands), `alias -g` for global aliases and `alias -s` for suffix aliases.

---

If you need to do this more often, just define a function in your `~/.zshrc` (or some other file you source from there)

```
reload-aliases () {
    unalias ${(k)aliases}
    source ~/.alias
}
```

Comment: Awesome; that's exactly what I needed. Just had to reload zsh `. ~/.zshrc`, and problem solved. I would upvote, but my reputation isn't high enough.

Comment: A much more zsh'ish way of removing all aliases is: `unalias ${(k)aliases}`, which does not neet an external command.

Comment: @mpy Thank you for the information on the `aliases` parameter. I incorporated it into my answer.